# npm - How to find the oldest version of a module with a particular update

Tags: node.js, npm

Npm module [async](https://github.com/caolan/async/) contains the **forEachOf** function in its latest version i.e 1.5.0 but not in the version 0.9.2. Is there a way to determine which is the oldest version of this module which contains the particular update ?

If yes, can it be generalized to updates of other modules as well?

Answer (score 0):

No. npm can only select a specific version, or the latest minor version of a major version. But there's nothing in npm to detect a specific feature.

All you can do if something like this :

```
"dependencies" : {
    "async" : ">=1.5.0"
}
```